# OpenBLAS + MinGW64 Static Link?

Tags: c++, mingw, static-libraries, blas, armadillo

I am able to compile Armadillo + OpenBLAS under MinGW64, however the link is through "libopenblas", which I believe is dll. Under Ubuntu I am able to link through "openblas" which I believe is static.

Under windows when I switch to "openblas" I got error messages:
bad reloc address 0x54
_gfortran_compare_string undefined reference

These errors persist when forcing "-static".

I wonder how can I force "-static" under windows so that my exe is independent of dlls. Thanks for any advise!

Best,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Also need to link "gfortran" when doing "-static".